# Are there any statements that can directly export the table creation scripts?

Tags: dolphindb

We have tables in the background. Are there any statements that can directly export the table creation script? We want to create a new table on another machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following custom function to export:

```py
/* @input  dbName: database name
 *         tableName: table name
 *  @output: information from creating the table
 *  @note
 *         
*/
def getDDL(dbName,tableName){
    //table not exist warning
    if(!existsTable(dbName,tableName)){
        return "Please check whether the table exists"
        }
    //Fields and field types
    col1= schema(loadTable(dbName,tableName)).colDefs.name
    col2= schema(loadTable(dbName,tableName)).colDefs.typeString
    col1 = "`"+concat(col1,"`")
    col2 = "["+concat(col2,",")+"]"

    //
    partitionCol = schema(loadTable(dbName,tableName)).partitionColumnName
    partitionCol = "`"+concat(partitionCol,"`")
    //print the information for the creation of table
        print("db = database("+'\"'+database+'\")')
    print("db.createPartitionedTable(table(1:0,"+col1+","+col2+"),`"+tableName+","+partitionCol+")")
}
```

```py
login(`admin,`123456)
getDDL("dfs://level2","quotes")
```